# For which $a \in \mathbb R$ does the line $y=a$ cut the graph of a sine function?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I really dont get this question. Dont I need to know what $a$ is?

Comment: The graph if a sine function is $y=\sin x$. So now you're graphing the following:
$$
\begin{cases}
y = \sin x \\
y = a
\end{cases}
$$
It should be clear that the two graphs "cut" each other when $\sin x = a$. For what values of $a$ does this equation have a solution? In other words, we're looking for the **range** of the $\sin x$. I suggest that you actually graph the functions and play around with the values.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more expanded version of the same problem. Maybe that helps you understand it better:

> Does the line $y=0$ cut the graph of a sine function? What about $y=2$? What about $y=-\frac12$? These are three possible lines, but there are many more. How can you tell, just by looking at the right-hand side of such an expression, whether the line it describes intersects the sine graph?